# Wordpress functions not available in template

Tags: php, wordpress

I am editing front-page.php and there I use `get_posts()` to output posts.
The other ways like using `the_post` are not working. So I need to output excerpt, but $post->post_excerpt is empty and `the_excerpt` function does nothing. I don't understand why, cause there are no errors. Here is the code:

```
<?php

    foreach ( get_posts() as $post ) { ?>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('article-item well'); ?>>
            <h2 class="title text-primary">
                <a href="<?php echo $post->guid; ?>">
                    <?php echo $post->post_title; ?>
                </a>
            </h2>
            <p class="article-info text-center">
            <span class="date">Posted on <time pubdate="" title="12:19 pm" datetime="<?php echo $post->post_date; ?>" class="time">
                    <?php echo $post->post_date; ?>
                </time>
            </span>
            </p>
            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
                <figure class="img-wrap">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
                    <figcaption class="label label-primary">
                        <?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
                            echo $category->cat_name . ' ';
                        } ?>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            <?php } ?>
            <p>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </p>
```

BTW `the_ID` function is working and outputs post's id properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On each iteration of the loop you need to 'setup' post data, you do this using `setup_postdata( $post );`

Amend your code as follows:

```
<?php

foreach ( get_posts() as $post ) { 
    setup_postdata( $post );
    ?>
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('article-item well'); ?>>
        <h2 class="title text-primary">
            <a href="<?php echo $post->guid; ?>">
                <?php echo $post->post_title; ?>
            </a>
        </h2>
        <p class="article-info text-center">
        <span class="date">Posted on <time pubdate="" title="12:19 pm" datetime="<?php echo $post->post_date; ?>" class="time">
                <?php echo $post->post_date; ?>
            </time>
        </span>
        </p>
        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
            <figure class="img-wrap">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
                <figcaption class="label label-primary">
                    <?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
                        echo $category->cat_name . ' ';
                    } ?>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        <?php } ?>
        <p>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </p>
```